# ejabberd how to compile on windows

Tags: ejabberd

Ejabberd has a [windows installer](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/) but the source does not compile for windows out of the box.

`configure.bat` has references to `configure.erl` but this file doesn't exist.
How do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, the windows installer is cross-compiled, or some weird stuff, and also requires specific program to pack the installer. So, building a Windows installer is not possible.

But you can download the ejabberd source code, make any changes you want to the erlang source code, compile it with the same Erlang/OTP version that is included in the Windows installer, and copy the *.beam files you have modified into the ejabberd installed directory.